# Air native extension: pass bitmapdata from thread (winapi) to as3

Tags: c++, multithreading, actionscript-3, winapi, air

In my native extension for air I want to create a screenshot. I managed to do this in synchronous way. Now I want to do it **asynchronous in a thread** (using WINAPI CreateThread).

In the thread I create new bitmapdata and set the color for each pixel. But now my question is:

**How do I pass the bitmapdata created in the thread back to actionscript?**

Here I create the thread:

```
FREObject getScreenShotAsynchronous(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    FREGetObjectAsInt32(argv[1], &_iSsWidth);
    FREGetObjectAsInt32(argv[2], &_iSsHeight);
    FREGetObjectAsInt32(argv[3], &_iSsOffsetX);
    FREGetObjectAsInt32(argv[4], &_iSsOffsetY);

    //Context ref for thread:
    oCtxThreadScreenshot = ctx;

    //Create thread:
    bRunThreadScreenshot = true;
    hThreadScreenshot = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadScreenshot, 0, 0, &dwThreadScreenshotID);
    CloseHandle(hThreadScreenshot);

    return NULL;
}
```

And here is the thread itself:

```
DWORD WINAPI threadScreenshot(LPVOID data)
{
    int32_t iWidth, iHeight, iOffsetX, iOffsetY;
    iWidth = _iSsWidth;
    iHeight = _iSsHeight;
    iOffsetX = _iSsOffsetX;
    iOffsetY = _iSsOffsetY;

    FREObject freWidth;
    FRENewObjectFromUint32(uint32_t(iWidth), &freWidth);

    FREObject freHeight;
    FRENewObjectFromUint32(uint32_t(iHeight), &freHeight);

    FREObject freTransparent;
    FRENewObjectFromBool(uint32_t(0), &freTransparent);

    FREObject freFillColor;
    FRENewObjectFromUint32(uint32_t(0xFF0000), &freFillColor);


    // first get those values from imaage
    FREObject freArguments[4] = { freWidth, freHeight, freTransparent, freFillColor };

    // create an instance of BitmapData
    FREObject freoBitmapData;
    FRENewObject((uint8_t *)"flash.display.BitmapData", 4, freArguments, &freoBitmapData, NULL);

    // now acquire the bitmap data in order to manipulate it
    FREBitmapData freBitmapData;
    FREAcquireBitmapData(freoBitmapData, &freBitmapData);

    //***
    //Grab screenshot data and fill bitmapdata...
    //**.

    // Tell Flash which region of the bitmapData changes (all of it here)
    FREInvalidateBitmapDataRect(freoBitmapData, 0, 0, freBitmapData.width, freBitmapData.height);
    // Release our control over the bitmapData
    FREReleaseBitmapData(freoBitmapData);

    //Dispatch event:
    FREDispatchStatusEventAsync(oCtxThreadScreenshot, (const uint8_t *)"onMsg", (const uint8_t *)"screenshot_done");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: if read documentation about say [FREAcquireBitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSb464b1207c184b14-62b8e11f12937b86be4-7ff8.html) - `FRE_WRONG_THREAD
    The method was called from a thread other than the one on which the runtime has an outstanding call to a native extension function.` are your code in thread work at all without this error `FRE_WRONG_THREAD` ?

Comment: I don't get such an error. The event "screenshot_done" is being dispatched.

Comment: you may save it as a temporary file then load it from as3

Comment: That would be very slow. The reason why I want to do it in a thread is to not block the main thread creating and filling the bitmap data - e.g. when getting the data from the clipboard the main thread has to create the new bitmpdata.

Comment: Ok, when I use FREGetContextActionScriptData inside the thread, I get the message FRE_WRONG_THREAD.

Answer (score 0):

- `std.IN/OUT` : Could **std in/out** be an option...?
- `return` : Would it be possible for the functions of your ANE to simply `return` the bitmapData instead of `null` and `0`? I don't use ANEs so maybe I'm wrong & it must be kept like that?

**std in/out** comes from when I use `NativeProcess` to run an external program & receive its data. A process thread is really just a program running, so hopefully you can do some **std** functions with it.

Comment: I don't have problems dispatching events (strings) to the main thread. But that is not bitmapdata.